# Is it possible to install Windows SDK for Windows 7 on Windows 8?

Tags: matlab, winapi, windows-8, failed-installation, matlab-compiler

I am trying to install `Windoes SDK for Windows 7 and .NET framework 4` for **MATLAB R2015b**, on **Windows 8**. But I get the following error:

> The windows installer is busy configuring another program

[image]

No other program is being installed at the same time though. What's the cause of this problem? Is it because it's not possible to install `Windows SDK 7` on Window 8?

Here is the output log when the installation fails:

```
10:03:12 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10:03:12 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Begin
10:03:12 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] SDKSetup Version 7.1.7600.30111
10:03:16 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] SDKSetupDll_DoTasks: Starting
10:03:16 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] SDKSetupDll_DoTasksWithGUI: Starting
10:03:17 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_OS_Detect: Operating system installation (detected)
10:03:18 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_MSI_Detect: Windows Installer Setup (detected)
10:03:18 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineProductState_Begin: Product: Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineProductState_End:   Product: Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_Begin: Feature: NativeDev
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState:       Feature: NativeDev;  Installed: Absent;  Request: None;
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_End:   Feature: NativeDev
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_Begin: Feature: ManagedDev
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState:       Feature: ManagedDev;  Installed: Absent;  Request: None;
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_End:   Feature: ManagedDev
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_Begin: Feature: CommonTools
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState:       Feature: CommonTools;  Installed: Absent;  Request: None;
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_End:   Feature: CommonTools
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_Begin: Feature: RedistComponents
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState:       Feature: RedistComponents;  Installed: Absent;  Request: None;
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_End:   Feature: RedistComponents
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_Begin: Feature: WinSDK_WinSDK
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState:       Feature: WinSDK_WinSDK;  Installed: Absent;  Request: Local;
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_End:   Feature: WinSDK_WinSDK
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_Begin: Feature: WinSDK_SFX
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState:       Feature: WinSDK_SFX;  Installed: Absent;  Request: Local;
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_End:   Feature: WinSDK_SFX
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_Begin: Feature: WinSDK_WinSDK_VC_Integration
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState:       Feature: WinSDK_WinSDK_VC_Integration;  Installed: Absent;  Request: Local;
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_End:   Feature: WinSDK_WinSDK_VC_Integration
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_Begin: Feature: WinSDKBuild_WinSDKBuild
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState:       Feature: WinSDKBuild_WinSDKBuild;  Installed: Absent;  Request: None;
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_End:   Feature: WinSDKBuild_WinSDKBuild
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_Begin: Feature: WinSDKTools_WinSDK_BIN_DevTools_Desktop
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState:       Feature: WinSDKTools_WinSDK_BIN_DevTools_Desktop;  Installed: Absent;  Request: None;
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_End:   Feature: WinSDKTools_WinSDK_BIN_DevTools_Desktop
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_Begin: Feature: WinSDK_WinSDK_BIN
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState:       Feature: WinSDK_WinSDK_BIN;  Installed: Absent;  Request: Local;
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_End:   Feature: WinSDK_WinSDK_BIN
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_Begin: Feature: WinSDKBuild_VistaHeadersLibs_VistaHeaders
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState:       Feature: WinSDKBuild_VistaHeadersLibs_VistaHeaders;  Installed: Absent;  Request: None;
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_End:   Feature: WinSDKBuild_VistaHeadersLibs_VistaHeaders
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_Begin: Feature: WinSDKBuild_VistaHeadersLibs_VistaLibs_X86
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState:       Feature: WinSDKBuild_VistaHeadersLibs_VistaLibs_X86;  Installed: Absent;  Request: None;
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_End:   Feature: WinSDKBuild_VistaHeadersLibs_VistaLibs_X86
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_Begin: Feature: WinSDKBuild_VistaHeadersLibs_VistaLibs_X64
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState:       Feature: WinSDKBuild_VistaHeadersLibs_VistaLibs_X64;  Installed: Absent;  Request: None;
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_End:   Feature: WinSDKBuild_VistaHeadersLibs_VistaLibs_X64
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_Begin: Feature: WinSDKBuild_VistaHeadersLibs_VistaLibs_IA64
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState:       Feature: WinSDKBuild_VistaHeadersLibs_VistaLibs_IA64;  Installed: Absent;  Request: None;
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_End:   Feature: WinSDKBuild_VistaHeadersLibs_VistaLibs_IA64
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_Begin: Feature: WinSDKCompiler_WinSDKCompiler_X64_Compilers
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState:       Feature: WinSDKCompiler_WinSDKCompiler_X64_Compilers;  Installed: Absent;  Request: None;
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_End:   Feature: WinSDKCompiler_WinSDKCompiler_X64_Compilers
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_Begin: Feature: WinSDK_WinSDK_RDC_X86_CRT
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState:       Feature: WinSDK_WinSDK_RDC_X86_CRT;  Installed: Absent;  Request: Local;
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_End:   Feature: WinSDK_WinSDK_RDC_X86_CRT
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_Begin: Feature: WinSDK_WinSDK_RDC_X64_CRT
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState:       Feature: WinSDK_WinSDK_RDC_X64_CRT;  Installed: Absent;  Request: Local;
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_End:   Feature: WinSDK_WinSDK_RDC_X64_CRT
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_Begin: Feature: WinSDK_WinSDK_RDC_IA64_CRT
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState:       Feature: WinSDK_WinSDK_RDC_IA64_CRT;  Installed: Absent;  Request: Local;
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_End:   Feature: WinSDK_WinSDK_RDC_IA64_CRT
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_Begin: Feature: WinSDKNetFx40Tools
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState:       Feature: WinSDKNetFx40Tools;  Installed: Absent;  Request: None;
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_End:   Feature: WinSDKNetFx40Tools
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_Begin: Feature: WinSDKInterop_Headers
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState:       Feature: WinSDKInterop_Headers;  Installed: Absent;  Request: None;
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_End:   Feature: WinSDKInterop_Headers
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_Begin: Feature: WinSDKInterop_X64Libs
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState:       Feature: WinSDKInterop_X64Libs;  Installed: Absent;  Request: None;
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_End:   Feature: WinSDKInterop_X64Libs
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_Begin: Feature: WinSDKInterop_x86Libs
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState:       Feature: WinSDKInterop_x86Libs;  Installed: Absent;  Request: None;
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_End:   Feature: WinSDKInterop_x86Libs
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_Begin: Feature: WinSDKInterop_IA64Libs
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState:       Feature: WinSDKInterop_IA64Libs;  Installed: Absent;  Request: None;
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_End:   Feature: WinSDKInterop_IA64Libs
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_Begin: Feature: F_NetFx_DTP
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState:       Feature: F_NetFx_DTP;  Installed: Absent;  Request: None;
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_End:   Feature: F_NetFx_DTP
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_Begin: Feature: IntellisenseNFX
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState:       Feature: IntellisenseNFX;  Installed: Absent;  Request: None;
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_End:   Feature: IntellisenseNFX
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_Begin: Feature: WinSDK_WinSDK_SMP_Win32
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState:       Feature: WinSDK_WinSDK_SMP_Win32;  Installed: Absent;  Request: None;
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_End:   Feature: WinSDK_WinSDK_SMP_Win32
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_Begin: Feature: WinSDKBuild_VistaHeadersLibs
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState:       Feature: WinSDKBuild_VistaHeadersLibs;  Installed: Absent;  Request: None;
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_End:   Feature: WinSDKBuild_VistaHeadersLibs
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_Begin: Feature: WinSDKWin32Tools_WinSDKWin32Tools
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState:       Feature: WinSDKWin32Tools_WinSDKWin32Tools;  Installed: Absent;  Request: None;
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_End:   Feature: WinSDKWin32Tools_WinSDKWin32Tools
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_Begin: Feature: WinSDKCompiler_WinSDKCompiler
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState:       Feature: WinSDKCompiler_WinSDKCompiler;  Installed: Absent;  Request: None;
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_End:   Feature: WinSDKCompiler_WinSDKCompiler
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_Begin: Feature: Intellisense_RefAssy
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState:       Feature: Intellisense_RefAssy;  Installed: Absent;  Request: None;
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_End:   Feature: Intellisense_RefAssy
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_Begin: Feature: WinSDKInterop_WinSDKInterop
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState:       Feature: WinSDKInterop_WinSDKInterop;  Installed: Absent;  Request: None;
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_End:   Feature: WinSDKInterop_WinSDKInterop
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_Begin: Feature: WinSDKNetFxTools_WinSDKNetFxTools
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState:       Feature: WinSDKNetFxTools_WinSDKNetFxTools;  Installed: Absent;  Request: None;
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_End:   Feature: WinSDKNetFxTools_WinSDKNetFxTools
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_Begin: Feature: WinSDKHelp
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState:       Feature: WinSDKHelp;  Installed: Absent;  Request: None;
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_End:   Feature: WinSDKHelp
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_Begin: Feature: WinSDKApplicationVerifier
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState:       Feature: WinSDKApplicationVerifier;  Installed: Absent;  Request: None;
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_End:   Feature: WinSDKApplicationVerifier
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_Begin: Feature: WinSDKPerformanceToolkit
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState:       Feature: WinSDKPerformanceToolkit;  Installed: Absent;  Request: None;
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_End:   Feature: WinSDKPerformanceToolkit
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_Begin: Feature: WinSDKDebuggingTools
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState:       Feature: WinSDKDebuggingTools;  Installed: Absent;  Request: None;
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_End:   Feature: WinSDKDebuggingTools
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_Begin: Feature: WinSDK_WinSDK_RDC
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState:       Feature: WinSDK_WinSDK_RDC;  Installed: Absent;  Request: Local;
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_End:   Feature: WinSDK_WinSDK_RDC
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_Begin: Feature: AppVerifierRedistComponents
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState:       Feature: AppVerifierRedistComponents;  Installed: Absent;  Request: None;
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_End:   Feature: AppVerifierRedistComponents
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_Begin: Feature: DebuggingToolsRedistComponents
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState:       Feature: DebuggingToolsRedistComponents;  Installed: Absent;  Request: None;
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_End:   Feature: DebuggingToolsRedistComponents
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_Begin: Feature: WinSDKRedistComponents
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState:       Feature: WinSDKRedistComponents;  Installed: Absent;  Request: None;
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_DetermineFeatureState_End:   Feature: WinSDKRedistComponents
10:53:42 AM Friday, October 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Error] Config_Products_Detect: Windows SDK installation (User Cancelled): [SDKSetup:Error] The user cancelled the current operation. Stack:    at SDKSetup.ConfigProducts.DoCurrentTask(TaskMode Task)
```

Comment: are you installing from the [iso](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowssdk/archive/2009/08/10/troubleshooting-windows-7-sdk-download-install.aspx)? If so it would be worth trying running the msi directly rather than the setup.exe.

Comment: A detailed instruction with some workarounds is available here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101105-how-do-i-install-microsoft-windows-sdk-7-1 It might be necessary to remove visual studio c++ and .net framework before proceeding with the setup.

Comment: @JayChase I did that, it says: "To install this product, please run setup.exe"

Comment: @Daniel I uninstalled them before proceeding, but the problem persists.

Comment: I remember having similar problems... and I remember I found a solution online (eventually), I currently have SDK for Windows 7 (7.1) working on Win 8.1, So it definitely can work... and the instructions to get it to work are around somewhere...

Answer (score 5):

Do you have access to a PC with windows 7, or a PC with the SDK already installed?  If so, the easiest solution is to copy the `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1` folder from the Win 7 machine to the Win 8 machine.

Otherwise, as @Daniel commented, you have to uninstall quite a lot of stuff, install the SDK, and then re-install everything.

Comment: Is this really successful? I would expect some registry keys and similar to be missing.

Comment: The vast majority of stuff in the SDK folder does not require registration.

Comment: I was expecting `mex -setup` to use some registry keys to identify the location, but it seems an [environment variable](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/100164-why-is-mex-setup-unable-to-locate-the-microsoft-platform-sdk) is used. At least this has to be created after copying the SDK to allow Matlab to find it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find something noticeable in your setup log , it said that every thing is OK and user canceled the operation .

> Microsoft Windows SDK, Platform SDK, and .NET Framework SDK are
>   software development kits from Microsoft that contain header files,
>   libraries, samples, documentation and tools required to develop
>   applications for Microsoft Windows and .NET Framework.[1]

and I think it defers in every versions so you have to Download the exact version same as your windows version